# How do I call a method that takes multiple parameters when I have a single list of values?

Tags: javascript, json

I am writing a way to store method calls into an object:

```
var action = {'method':'foo', 'params': [1,'bob',45]}
```

I have my methods:

```
function foo(order, name, size);

function bar(input);

function baz(name, length, time, debug);
```

etc

When given an action I wish to automatically call the function associated with it:

```
var fn = window[action.method]
if(typeof fn === 'function')
{
    fn(//blah)
}
```

The problem is, the action object has a list of parameters, but my functions take multiple parameters. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `.apply`:

```
fn.apply( this, action.params );
```

This calls `fn`, but uses the first argument to set the `this` value of `fn`, and uses the individual members of the second argument (the `action.params` array) to populate the arguments of the call as individual arguments.

---

I'd note that since you're doing:

```
window[action.method]
```

that you actually have the method name as a string:

```
{'method':'foo',...}
```